# ¿Por qué este "Dia" no lleva tilde?

Tags: ortografía, nombres-propios, siglas

Yo estaba convencido de que los nombres propios seguían las normas de ortografía (pese a haber llegado incluso a ver un "Iban" escrito tal que así en el DNI).

En España hay una empresa (una cadena de supermercados llamada [Dia](https://www.dia.es/compra-online/)). Lo mire donde lo mire, Dia aparece sin tilde. [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermercados_Dia) explica que el nombre de la empresa es

> **D**istribuidora **I**nternacional de **A**limentación, **DIA**

Y por un lado y otro explica que

> La filosofía proporcionada por **Dia** es [...]
>
> La cadena **Dia** fue creada en España en 1979 con [...]

Entiendo que el nombre "DIA" es un acrónimo, aunque lo vea escrito con mayor frecuencia como "Dia" que "DIA".

Aunque no lo he encontrado en la RAE (sí en [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/los-nombres-propios-tambien-siguen-las-normas-de-ortografia-te-pongas-como-te-pongas/)), cualquier búsqueda en al red lo confirma: **Los nombres propios también siguen las normas de ortografía**.

Tal vez el enlace más relevante es  [¿Para los nombres propios no existen reglas ortográficas? | Noticia](http://www.duoc.cl/ver/noticia/para-los-nombres-propios-no-existen-reglas-ortograficas) que explica:

> A los nombres propias se les aplican las mismas reglas de ortografía que al resto de las palabras en el español, tanto en la *acentuación* como en las letras que lo componen. La idea de que "los nombres de las personas no tienen ortografía" es porque cada quien puede inscribir un nombre con una forma ortográfica determinada en el registro civil, como por ejemplo: Helena, Elena, Ema, Emma, etc.
>
> Respecto a la acentuaciá, por us caracter discrimnatorio, si alguien decidiera escribir su apellido como "Gonzalez"(sin tilde), deberá asumir que los demas lo pronuncien como palabra aguda ("Gonzaléz").

Aparte, en [¿Tienen los nombres propios ortografía?](https://www.upb.edu.co/es/blogs/palabras-en-orden/escritura-y-ortografia-de-nombres-propios) se dice que

> Dice la RAE que, en cuanto a la utilización de letras, se debe respetar la forma como nos registraron, pero, en cuanto a lo no escritura de las tildes, ellos afirman, que si nuestros nombres y apellidos, **por reglas de acentuación de palabras, llevan tilde, así nos hayan registrado sin ellas, hay que ponerlas**. Esto debido a que son términos comunes y corrientes y, como tal, deben cumplir con todas las normas ortográficas.

Entonces mi pregunta es por qué el nombre de la empresa Dia no lleva tilde. ¿Es porque se trata de un acrónimo? ¿O es porque ellos han querido registrarla así pero debería llevar tilde?

No creo que un nombre propio, por el hecho de ser un acrónimo, esté exento de cumplir las reglas de  ortografía, pero lo mismo me equivoco y hay una regla al respecto.

Comment: Diego, es perfectamente posible que ese «Iban» que tanto escozor te causó en un DNI sea un nombre vasco. Saludos desde México

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DIA no lleva tilde porque es una *[sigla](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nNmc4LzNaD6zHPhgWc) que se pronuncia como una palabra,* un tipo de *[acrónimo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tvd5E55ArD6uxbj2i5)*.

Estos, cuando se incorporan al léxico común (o tienen más de cuatro letras, según el DPD), pasan a escribirse en minúsculas y con tilde, si es necesario, pero antes no.

> Las siglas presentan normalmente en mayúscula todas las letras que las componen (*OCDE, DNI, ISO*) y, en ese caso, **no llevan nunca tilde**; así, *CIA* (del ingl. *Central Intelligence Agency*) se escribe sin tilde, a pesar de pronunciarse [sía, zía], con un hiato que exigiría acentuar gráficamente la *i*. Las siglas que se pronuncian como se escriben, esto es, los acrónimos, se escriben solo con la inicial mayúscula si se trata de nombres propios y tienen más de cuatro letras: *Unicef, Unesco*; o con todas sus letras minúsculas, si se trata de nombres comunes: *uci, ovni, sida*. Los acrónimos que se escriben con minúsculas sí deben someterse a las reglas de acentuación gráfica: *láser*.

<sup>DPD, [“Sigla”](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nNmc4LzNaD6zHPhgWc). (El resaltado es mío.)</sup>

Lo de escribir DIA como “Dia” es cosa de los redactores de Wikipedia. La propia empresa sólo utiliza “DIA”. Lo único que más o menos se parece a “Dia” en sus publicaciones es el logo.

Nótese, eso sí, que cuando la empresa escribe “DIA” en minúsculas, **sí** le pone tilde, como en el logo de “Cada DIA”.

[image]